# Get list of properties from collection Into unified list using Guava

Tags: java-7, guava

My company requires that we use Guava's functions & predicates whenever we loop through a collection of objects. While I don't necessarily agree that it should be this way, it's my companies standard so please don't give me comments about how it's not efficient or things like that :)

I need, using Guava in Java 1.7 specifically, to find a way to take a collection of objects, and get all of the inner fields into a unified list. This is as far as I've gotten but I have not been able to get inner fields:

```
public static final Function<Group, String> GROUP_TO_GROUP_NAME =
  new Function<Group, String>()
{
  @Override
  public String apply(Group group)
  {
    return group.getGroupName();
  }
};

public static List<String> transformToGroupNames(List<GroupCollection> groupCollections)
{
  List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
  for (GroupCollection groupCollection: groupCollections)
  {
    groups.addAll(groupCollection.getGroups());
  }
  return FluentIterable.from(groups)
    .transform(GROUP_TO_GROUP_NAME)
    .filter(Predicates.notNull())
    .toList();
}
```

My goal is to replace the loop through the groupCollections

Comment: I have to say it: does your company know the Guava documentation itself says that's a bad idea?

Comment: Ha, I'm not in a place to say whether or not the team who does the review process knows a lot. I think this comment is useful because it's very correct. The developers don't want it being used as a blanket library. Sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flatten the group collections to a single group collection you can use [`FluentIterable.transformAndConcat(Function)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#transformAndConcat(com.google.common.base.Function)):

```
public static final Function<GroupCollection, List<Group>> GROUP_COLLECTIONS_TO_GROUP_COLLECTION =
        new Function<GroupCollection, List<Group>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Group> apply(GroupCollection input) {
                return input.getGroups();
            }
        };

public static final Function<Group, String> GROUP_TO_GROUP_NAME =
        new Function<Group, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(Group group) {
                return group.getGroupName();
            }
        };

public static List<String> transformToGroupNames(List<GroupCollection> groupCollections) {
    return FluentIterable.from(groupCollections)
            .transformAndConcat(GROUP_COLLECTIONS_TO_GROUP_COLLECTION)
            .transform(GROUP_TO_GROUP_NAME)
            .filter(Predicates.notNull())
            .toList();
}
```